# Cylindrical co-ordinates

Tags: calculus

Find the volume of the solid enclosed between
the spheres:

$$x^2+y^2+z^2=4$$, $$x^2+y^2+z^2=4z$$
I'm trying to do this in spherical co ordinates but I can't get the right $$\phi$$ and $$\theta$$. I think $$\rho$$ is between 0 and 2 though. Can anyone help me find the other two

Comment: 1) $\phi, \theta, \rho$ symbols ususally denote spherical coordinates, cylindrical ones are usually named $\rho,\theta,z$, if I recall correctly. 2) Try adding $4-4z$ to both sides of the second equation, you may find some simplification of it.

Comment: turns out i should use cylindrical co-ordinates, but how do I know when to use each method?

Comment: You have two spheres here, but they are not concentric so it is difficult to express boundary of integration in spherical coordinates. However you can exploit the rotational symmetry of both spheres with respect to the common axis, which is a line passing through centres of both spheres, That leads to cylindrical coordinates. Just identify both centers and find a line through them, then define a cylindr.coord. system with that line as its axis and transform both spheres' equations into a new system.

Comment: You can use single instead of double dollar signs to get inline math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to find the volume of the region given by points whose distance from $(0,0,0)$ is $\leq 2$ and whose distance from $(0,0,2)$ is $\leq 2$. By symmetry, such volume is twice the volume enclosed by $z=1$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$, hence, by Cavalieri's principle:
$$ 2\int_{1}^{2}\pi(4-z^2)\,dz=\color{red}{\frac{10\,\pi}{3}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

In cylindrical coordinates

Limitsfor z will be $\sqrt{4-r^2}+2 $ to $ \sqrt {4-r^2} $ and  in XY plane region  will be unit circle centered at origin. .which can be found out by solving for z in two equations for sphere

Comment: i got your limits and stuff but  I still cant get the right answer?

Comment: I cannot help you furthure as i donor know

Comment: You got the limits incorrect, it's meant to be -2 instead of +2. This is because we're taking from the bottom half of the sphere not the top half